# Prolog: Finding next date

Tags: date, time, prolog

So, I'm stuck with this problem for hours and I cant seem to find a solution.
I need to, given a current date, and knowing that airplanes take off on tuesday, thursday and saturday at 6:00, calculate the date and time of the next departure.
I put this information in the form of facts (second argument represents day of week where 1=Monday):

```
departure(time(6,0,0), 2).
departure(time(6,0,0), 4).
departure(time(6,0,0), 6).
```

Can someone help me out?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following solution and I'll try to esplain it

```
selNextDepH([], _, First, First).

selNextDepH([Hd | _], Now, _, Hd) :-
  Now @<= Hd.

selNextDepH([Hd | Td], Now, First, NextDep) :-
  Now @> Hd,
  selNextDepH(Td, Now, First, NextDep).

selNextDep([Hd | Td], Now, NextDep) :-
  selNextDepH([Hd | Td], Now, Hd, NextDep).

switchDep(dep(Day, Time), departure(Time, Day)).

nextDep(DayNow, TimeNow, NextDeparture) :-
  findall(dep(Day, Time), departure(Time, Day), List),
  sort(List, ListS),
  selNextDep(ListS, dep(DayNow, TimeNow), NextDep),
  switchDep(NextDep, NextDeparture).
```

All start in `nextDep/3` where `findall/3` collect all `departure/2` but collect they as `dep/2`, in reverse order (`dep(Day, Time)` instead `departure(Time, Day)`) because it's easier to order

```
  findall(dep(Day, Time), departure(Time, Day), List),
```

Next we sort the list `List` of `dep/2` structs with `sort/2`

```
  sort(List, ListS),
```

so in `ListS` (list sorted) we have the departures (in `dep/2` form) ordered with the day as first key and the time as second.

Next we call `selNextDep/3` to find the next departure in `dep/2` form (`NextDep`)

```
selNextDep(ListS, dep(DayNow, TimeNow), NextDep),
```

and, with `switchDep/2`, we obtain the next departure in `departure/2` form

```
switchDep(NextDep, NextDeparture).
```

`swithcDep/2` is trivial but `selNextDep/3` isn't (IMHO).

The idea behind `selNextDep/3` is return (in the third argument) the first `sel/2` element of the sorted list (the first argument) that is bigger that the second argument (the time now). If no bigger element is found, the idea is return the first element of the list (the first departure in the next week).

So I've delevoped a simple `selNextDep/3` that only call a helper clause (`selNextDepH/4`) with the same arguments and added the first element of the list (in case of failure in finding a bigger element); that is

```
selNextDep([Hd | Td], Now, NextDep) :-
  selNextDepH([Hd | Td], Now, Hd, NextDep).
```

For `selNextDepH/4` the terminal clause is trivial: if the list is empty, return (unify with the last argument) the first element of the list

```
selNextDepH([], _, First, First).
```

If the list isn't empty, we have 2 cases: (1) the now-time is lower (or equal) than the first element of the list, so we return (unify the last argument) the first element of the list

```
selNextDepH([Hd | _], Now, _, Hd) :-
  Now @<= Hd.
```

or (2) the time-now is bigger than the first argument of the list, so we look for a bigger departure in the next of the list

```
selNextDepH([Hd | Td], Now, First, NextDep) :-
  Now @> Hd,
  selNextDepH(Td, Now, First, NextDep).
```